# Store all JSON in Map using gson and Retrofit 2

Tags: json, dictionary, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm getting a JSON value from an API using Retrofit. However since the actual keys are going to be different each time I request the data, I'd like to store everything in a Map. Is this possible using Gson as the parser?

For example:
Access #1:

```
{
    "name": "Toby",
    "color": "blue"
}
```

Access #2:

```
{
    "game": "Soccer",
    "day": "Monday"
}
```

Instead of creating a class such as

```
class MyValues {
    public String name;
    public String color;
}
```

which would be impossible since the keys will always be different, I'd like something like:

```
class MyValues {
    public Map<String, String> myMap;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you don't need the `MyValues` class, you can use just `Map<String, String>` as the parameter type for your retrofit `Call`. --

```
@GET("/")
Call<Map<String, String>> myCall();
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with retrofit 1?